# Ruby: Change button text to icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My submit button for a comment displays a grey dull button that says "Create Comment". I want to instead display an icon.

I have tried...

```
<%= f.submit do %>
  <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %>
```

...with no luck

Comment: It sounds like you are using this library. http://fontawesome.io/icon/paper-plane-o/ What code did you add to your project to include this library? "fa-paper-plane-o" will not work without adding this library.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your font awesome gem in your gem file and bundled ?
You also need it to be called in your application.css file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= f.image_submit_tag(‘<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>’).html_safe %>
```

Reference: [image_submit_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag)

Comment: I have font-awesome working. And I think you misunderstood. I'm not looking for my button to say "Create Comment", instead I want to display only the icon. The above did not work.

Comment: Then, try this: f.image_submit_tag(‘<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>’).html_safe

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<%= button_tag(class: "btn btn-default") do %>
   <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

`<%= f.submit '<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe %>`